# good example liftweb app using Google Map API?

Tags: google-maps, scala, lift

Anyone know of any good examples of using Google Map API from within a scala liftweb app?

Comment: Well, foursquare use it, I suppose…

Answer (score 3):

Check out the TravelCompanionScala Sample App:
http://github.com/rmuri/TravelCompanionScala

It runs with Scala 2.8.0 final

The Stages are displayed on GoogleMaps.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a clean example https://github.com/joestein/cronus meant to just help implement a Google Map in the latest Lift version.

Comment: This one is really REALLY nice! Very plain and easy to use! Thank you so much! :) That's what i meant on my ScalaLol 2011 Talk! :)